# Show a subring of the ring of formal power series is finite generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and $F[[X]]$ be the ring of formal power series over F.
Let $$R=\{a+X^2 f(X):a∈F,f(X)∈F[[X]]\}$$ and let $\alpha\in F[[X]]$. Show the subring of $F[[X]]$ that generated by $R$ and $\alpha$, $R[\alpha]$, is a finite generated $R$-module.

I am not sure about this question, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is $K = F$? ${}{}$

Comment: yeah, they are, typo, sorry.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221392/algebra-integral-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Write $\alpha = a_0 + a_1X + X^2f_\alpha(X)$, $f_\alpha(X) \in F\def\p{[\![X]\!]}\p$. Then 
\begin{align*}
  \alpha^2 &= a_0^2 + 2a_0a_1X + X^2g_\alpha(X)
\end{align*}
for some $g_\alpha(X) \in F\p$. Hence 
$$ \alpha^2 = 2a_0\alpha - \underbrace{\bigl(a_0^2 + 2a_0X^2f_\alpha(X) - X^2g_\alpha(X)\bigr)}_{\in R} $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I guess then I use induction to show $\alpha^3 $ also is a combination of element in $R$? but why do we know $R[α]$ is finite generated?

Comment: As $\alpha^2 \in R + R\alpha$, induction shows that $R[\alpha] \subseteq R + R\alpha$. So $R[\alpha]$ is generated by $1$ and $\alpha$ **as an $R$-module**.